# VueJS 3 Ternary Operation on submitting a form

Tags: vuejs3

I was wondering this isn't working

```
 <form @submit.prevent="isEditMode? handleEditRole : handleAddRole">
```

But when I tried

```
<form @submit.prevent="handleAddRole">
```

or handleEditRole, its working just fine.

I'm setting the isEditMode to false when the user click the Add Role but then they chose to edit a role then isEdmitMode will be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue will not execute the function when it is returned from a ternary, you have to execute it yourself:

```html
 <form @submit.prevent="isEditMode? handleEditRole($event) : handleAddRole($event)">
```